# My screen is not reflective (not responding)while taking screenshot in iOS?

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext

I had an application on which I am capturing the screenshot of `UIWebView` on real time and sending it to server. In order to get a start I just changed the background color of the view and took the screenshot of that.

```
for (int i = 0; i <15; i++)
    {
        [NSThread sleepUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];
        NSLog(@"Delaying");

         self.view.backgroundColor=[self randomColor];


        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rec afterScreenUpdates:YES];

        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I am doing this like this. But the screen is not updating, it is in a kind of freezed mode. Its only updating after taking the last screen shot with last color. Can anybody help me to find out where I am going wrong? I need to take the screenshot of our app screens on real time.

Comment: If you were waiting a bit longer, watch dog would just kill your app. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[NSThread sleepUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]];` will cause your app to freeze because it will cause the main thread to sleep, if you are trying to delay taking the screenshot, use GCD's dispatch_after funcction

```
for (int i = 0; i <15; i++)
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(i * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //body of your forloop goes here
    });
}
```

May want to add i+1 to the delay if you dont want to take the initial screenshot immediately